# What kind of geometric series is $f(m) = \sum_{r=1}^{m}\frac{r+1}{n-r-1}$?

Tags: geometric-series

I have a geometric series that looks like 
$$
f(m) = \sum_{r=1}^{m}\frac{r+1}{n-r-1} \\
= \frac{2}{n-2} + \frac{3}{n-3} + \frac{4}{n-4} + \cdots + \frac{m+1}{n-(m-1)} \\
$$
I wrote out a few terms to see if I can identify a simplification but I couldn't. What kind of geometries series is this, and how can I simplify to get a closed form expression

Comment: It is not geometric.

Comment: The definition of geometric is that consecutive terms divided give a constant.

Comment: Why do you think it is any kind of geometric series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming $n$ is fixed. Note that in order for the sum to be well-defined, we must have $n \leq m$.

A closed form is unlikely, but:
\begin{align*}
f(m) &= \sum_{r=1}^m \frac{r+1}{n - (r + 1)} \\
&= \sum_{r=1}^m \left(\frac{n}{n - (r + 1) }- 
 1\right) \\
&= n\sum_{r=1}^m \frac{1}{n - (r + 1)} - m \\
&= n(H_{n-2} - H_{n-m-2}) - m
\end{align*}
where $H_k$ is the [$k^\text{th}$ harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Is $H_{n-2} - H_m$ right? I got the following:
$$
\bigg[n \bigg( \frac{1}{n-2} + \frac{1}{n-3} + \cdots + 1] + [\frac{1}{-1} + \frac{1}{-2} \cdots \frac{1}{n-(m+1)}\bigg)\bigg] -m \\
    = \bigg[n \bigg( \frac{1}{n-2} + \frac{1}{n-3} + \cdots + 1 \bigg) - \bigg(\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} \cdots \frac{1}{|n-(m+1)|}\bigg)\bigg] -m
$$

Oh wait, are you assuming $m < n$?

Comment: @dd22205 yes I'm assuming $m \leq n$. I'll add that in my answer. If $m \geq m + 1$, then your sum can't be well-defined as you'll have a $\frac{1}{0}$ term.

Comment: Ah yes, that's right. Shouldn't it be $H_{n-2} - H_{n-(m)}$?

Comment: @dd22205 you're right, I've edited my answer.

Comment: My bad. There's it's actually $H_{n-m-2}$. Went in the wrong direction.